# How to parsing list in prolog until not fail

Tags: prolog

I am trying to parse a list, for example:
`[1,3,3,2,2,7,2,9]`

Let's say I have the following code, where isTwo will print `No` and fail if it is anything other than two. I WANT it to fail if it is anything other than two. If it is a two, it will print `Yes` and succeed.

```
isTwo(2) :- 
    write('Yes'), !.

isTwo(_) :- 
    write('No'), fail.
```

My issue is that I have something along the lines of an iterator defined, and I want to parse an entire list to find the first success.

```
iter([]).

iter([Head|Tail]) :-
    isTwo(Head),
    iter(Tail).
```

This works fine but will stop parsing the rest of the list as soon as failure is found. If we go back to the original list, `[1,3,3,2,2,7,2,9]`, we get `false` as our output.

My question here is: how can I continue to parse in prolog while still ensuring that `isTwo(_)` (where it is not equal to two) will still fail, so that I can get an output of something such as `NoNoNoYesYesNoYesNo` in this case. Preferably without using an if-then-else clause.

This may help:

expected output: `NoNoNoYesYesNoYesNo`

observed output: `No`

Comment: Just get rid of the `fail`. You are making this harder on yourself than you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Well an easy solution would be to use a second variable in `iter` that will help you understand if an number different than 2 is found:

```
isTwo(2, X, X) :- 
    write('Yes').

isTwo(_, _, 0) :- 
    write('No').


iter([],  0):- fail,!.
iter([],  1).
iter([Head|Tail], X) :-
    isTwo(Head, X, Y),
    iter(Tail, Y).


iter(L) :- iter(L, 1).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more concise solution, using `maplist/2` you can do something like:

```
isTwo(2) :- write('Yes'), !.
isTwo(_):- write('No').

test(L):-
    maplist(isTwo,L).

?- test([1,3,3,2,2,7,2,9]).
NoNoNoYesYesNoYesNo
true
```

`test/1` is not mandatory, i've added it only for sake of clarity...

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are both fine but the haphazard mixing in of side effects makes me a bit nervous. Also, you have a problem if the list you are "parsing" has a free variable (it will become `2` silently).

Why not like this:

```
is_two(X) :- X == 2, !, format("Yes").
is_two(X) :- X \== 2, !, format("No").
```

and then:

```
?- forall(member(X, [1,3,3,2,2,7,2,9]), is_two(X)).
NoNoNoYesYesNoYesNo
true.

?- forall(member(X, [Y, 2, Z]), is_two(X)).
NoYesNo
true.
```

Use `==` and `\==` to compare without unifying. Use `forall` and `member` to make it clear that you are doing it for the side effect. Traversing a list (or using `maplist`) is a bit deceiving.

`forall` is just a clearer way to do a failure-driven loop using negation instead of cuts and fails. The query above is identical to:

```
?- \+ ( member(X, [1,3,3,2,2,7,2,9]), \+ is_two(X) ).
```